# SQL-SERVER Get Result from table where Value like 1-9

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table WHERE there's a column that has QTY Ranges like 1-5, 6-9 etc and prices in another column. i.e

```
Price QTY
------------------------
Price         Qty Range
-----         ----------
45            1-5
35            6-9
30            10-18
```

Now I want to get the result from the table where Qty is 7 Therefore Price returned should be 35 ( since Qty 7 falls in range 6-9

Any help greatly appriciated

Comment: If possible, change the design so that the lower and upper bounds are stored in separate, appropriate (e.g. `int`) columns. It's then a straightforward query.

Comment: Can't actually Change the Table structure since I do not have access to files, I just can use SQL and use result in XML that's all.

Comment: Also table is being used at many places throughout the website. so can't change the table structure.

Comment: one question then why you don't use switch case in your code to say for the case where number is greater than 6 and less than 9 (i.e. 7 in your case)then it should pick up price for 6-9 range

Comment: The problem is, it looks like the table has been designed for *display* purposes rather than for efficient querying. Given a table containing two `int` columns, it's *trivial* to display those as two values separated by a hyphen. Instead, with the current design, as per my answer, we have to do annoying string manipulation, which also precludes any possible benefits that indexing could produce, if the system has to scale.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
  Declare @val int
  Set @val=7

 ;with cte(price,startVal,endVal) as
  ( Select price,
    parsename(replace([Qty Range],'-','.'),2),
    parsename(replace([Qty Range],'-','.'),1)
    from yourTable
  )
  Select Price from cte 
  where @val between startVal and endVal
```

Result : `35`

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54e1c/7)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't redesign the table to be sane, you can use a couple of [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to reconstruct it as a sane table for this query:

```
declare @PriceRanges table (Price int,QtyRange varchar(20))
insert into @PriceRanges (Price,QtyRange) values
(45,'1-5'),
(35,'6-9'),
(30,'10-18')

declare @Search int
set @Search = 7

;with FoundDashes as (
    select Price,QtyRange,CHARINDEX('-',QtyRange) as DashPos
    from @PriceRanges
)
, SaneRanges as (
    select Price,CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(QtyRange,1,DashPos-1)) as LowRange,CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(QtyRange,DashPos+1,8000)) as HighRange
    from FoundDashes
)
select Price from SaneRanges where @Search between LowRange and HighRange
```

Produces `35` as a result.

Comment: Thanks Damien for Help You and parveen suggested almost same way and it worked like charm.

Comment: I am trying to create a Function for this

<pre>